# Output comes 1 clock cycle later than expected

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

I want to test a simple Verilog module that outputs `1` if the minterms `2`, `3`, `5` or `7` are found in a 3-variable input.

The module looks like this:

```
module modified_prime_detector(
  input [2:0] in,
  input clk,
  output reg out
);
  
  always @ (posedge clk)
  begin
    out <= (~in[2] && in[1] && ~in[0]) || (~in[2] && in[1] && in[0]) || (in[2] && ~in[1] && in[0]) || (in[2] && in[1] && in[0]);
   end
endmodule
```

I have also developed a testbench in order to run my simulation using **EDA Playground**:

```
module modified_prime_detector_tb();
    reg [2:0] in;
    reg clk;
    wire out;

    modified_prime_detector uut (
        .clk(clk),
        .in(in),
        .out(out)
    );

    always #5 clk = ~clk;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (in == 3'b111)
            in <= 3'b000;
        else
            in <= in + 1'b1;
    end
  
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
        $display("Time: %t, in: %b, out: %b", $time, in, out);
  end

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
        $dumpvars(1, modified_prime_detector_tb);
      
        clk = 0;
        in = 0;
      
        #5;
        #100;
        $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

Basically, I'm increasing the 3-bit value of `in` on each clock cycle. I then expect to see the `out`'s value set to `1` for the values: `010`, `011`, `101` and `111`.

However, I see that the module outputs `1` for these values: `011`, `100`, `110` and `000`? I'm not sure why it works like that. I think it might have to do with the simulation, because this is how the waveforms look like:

[image]

It seems that the output is "right-shifted" by one, at it also seems like my module gives no output for the input `000`. Unfortunately, I'm not sure why this happens and how to further investigate this issue.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue in the output, it is correct but your intuition is wrong. In your module you are using the non-blocking statement `<=` and that is the standard behavior of the non-blocking statement that the output occurs after one clock cycle. This is the same reason as to why you cannot see output at `000` condition because output will arrive one cycle later.

If you want your output to occur upon arrival of input then you should use the combinational logic by replacing the `posedge clk` in the sensitivity list with `in` and use `=`.

```
always @ (in) begin
    out = (~in[2] && in[1] && ~in[0]) || (~in[2] && in[1] && in[0]) || (in[2] && ~in[1] && in[0]) || (in[2] && in[1] && in[0]);
end
```

Now if you do this, the your logic is no longer depends on the clock. Secondly I have noticed that your input is 3-bit and in the test bench you are checking if `in == 3'b111` and then you reset it to `in <= 3'b000`, but there is no need to check this. Because if you add `1` in 3'b111, it will automatically become '0'. So you can simply write this in your test bench:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
     in <= in + 1'b1;
end
```